# How do I format an integer using Coldfusion?

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, number-formatting, coldfusion-10

I'm trying to use `NumberFormat`, on an integer, in order to pad it with leading zeroes. Unfortunately, `NumberFormat` seems to have no affect on the integer. Any advice would be appreciated.

```
 <cffunction name="myFunction" access="remote" returntype="numeric">
    <cfargument name="myId" type="numeric" required="yes" />
        <cfquery name="myQuery">
            SELECT COUNT(fileid) AS itemCount FROM files
            WHERE directory = '#myId#'
        </cfquery>
        <cfset newId = numberFormat( myQuery.itemCount, '0000000' )>
        <cfreturn newId />
</cffunction>
```

Comment: `writeDump(NumberFormat(5, "0000000"));` gives me `0000005`, regardless of whether or not it is a string or number to begin with. You sure the problem isn't elsewhere?

Comment: Ah, i see `returntype="numeric"`. Is coldfusion converting your string `00005` to it's numeric equivalent `5`?

Comment: Yes. Coldfusion appears to be unable to format a MySql COUNT statement.

Comment: What happens if you move the formatting to your MySQL statement? `SELECT LPAD(CAST(COUNT(fileid) AS CHAR), 5, '0')`

Comment: Not related to your question, but there are several things wrong with your query.  1. Not using query parameters.  2. not scoping your variable.  3.  quoting a number.

Answer (score 11):

Change your return type to a string. I'm pretty sure numeric will truncate leading zeros. Also, as a good practice, add`output="false"` to all your `<cfcomponent>` and `<cffunction>` tags.

Comment: I changed the return type to string. The return is still unformatted.

Comment: Please add more info on how you are testing your result. I just tested it on my CF10 server. It came back correct with the following: 
<wddxPacket version='1.0'><header/><data><string>0000013</string></data></wddxPacket>

Comment: (Edit) @jayron - Chris is correct. Type "numeric" will truncate leading zeroes. Using `returntype="string"` works. However, I noticed your method has `access="remote"`. Refresh the wsdl first, as it is possible you are using a cached version. Side note, nothing to do with your question, but be sure to scope all function local variables with `Local/var` (including query names).

Comment: Ah hah! Thanks Chris. This wasn't a Coldfusion issue; it was a Flash Builder 4.7 issue. More specifically, the programmer, who shall remain nameless, using Flash Builder 4.7 accidentally converted the Coldfusion returned string back to an integer.

Comment: Glad you found the issue. Please mark this question as answered.

Answer (score -4):

Try using [Val()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6e64.html) instead.

```
<cfset newId = Val(myQuery.itemCount)>
```

Comment: Same issue with VAL; Coldfusion returns the integer unformatted.

Comment: val() only makes sure it's a number. It will not format or change type.

Comment: Also, `val()` removes any leading zeroes.  To preserve leading zeroes, you must return a "string", not "numeric".